# php mysql_insert_id on multiple rows?

Tags: php, sql, insert

Is it possible to get the auto incremented ids from a query which inserts multiple rows?
eg:

INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);

Alteratively, is there a way to find the NEXT auto increment value WITHOUT inserting anything into the table?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know auto_increment does not fill gaps between ids and the operation is atomic. So you can assume that they will be in a row.

Comment: MySql supports auto increment offsets (this is more common in replication) so consecutive id's is not a guarantee in all environments.

Comment: You may safely assume consecutive ids under the [following circumstances](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) in MySql: you are using InnoDB, innodb_autoinc_lock_mode is set to 0 or 1 (default).

Answer (score 4):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

> If you insert multiple rows using a single `INSERT` statement, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the value generated for the first inserted row only.

So no, you can't get all the ids easily, but you can *assume* that they are continuous. You should **never** rely on assumptions though. It sounds like you want to guess the next `id` that would come after your bulk insert? If so, do not even attempt this and think of another way to do whatever it is you want to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the next auto_increment id you can use:

```
SELECT auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'table-you-want-to-check';
```

However, you may not want to rely on the `auto_increment` id or `last_insert_id()` in your code's logic. For example, let's say two people, A & B, are adding questions to your db at close to the same moment and you're using the `last_insert_id()` to determine the id of the person's question. What happens when they both submit their question at the same time? Is the `last_insert_id()` from person A or B?

One method to overcome this issue is to use a "pre-defined" id or [guid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) in addition to or in place of the auto incremented id.